# I created a custom gym environment for osu, but agent doesn't make any progress

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

This is my code:

```
def resize_frame(frame, width, height):
    return cv2.resize(frame, (width, height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)


def restart():
    print("restart")
    pyautogui.keyDown('esc')
    pyautogui.keyUp('esc')
    pyautogui.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.keyDown('enter')
    pyautogui.keyUp('enter')


class OsuInterface:
    prev_nums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    check = False
    nums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080)
    target_width, target_height = 96, 54
    done = False
    number = 0.0
    check = False
    prev_nums = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    prev_numbers = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.done = False

    def get_state(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()

        gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        resized_frame = resize_frame(gray_frame, self.target_width, self.target_height)
        return resized_frame

    def perform_action(self, action):
        x, y = action[0], action[1]
        # print(f"x:{x}, y:{y}")
        if (x > 1.0 or y > 1.0) or (x > 95.0 or y > 53.0):
            pyautogui.moveTo(x * 20, y * 20, 0)
            reward = self.get_reward()
        else:
            reward = -1
        if self.number > 100:
            self.number = 1
            return self.get_state(), reward, True, {}
        self.number += 1
        return self.get_state(), reward, False, {}

    def get_reward(self):
        with open('rttp-hit.txt', 'r') as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()

        def parse_line(line):
            numbers = list(map(int, line.rstrip(';').split(';')))
            diffs = [n - p for n, p in zip(numbers, self.prev_numbers or numbers)]
            rewards = {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 3, 3: 1}
            output = sum(rewards.get(i, -1) for i, d in enumerate(diffs) if d == 1)
            return output, numbers

        output = 0  # initialize output
        for line in lines:
            if line:
                output, numbers = parse_line(line)
                self.prev_numbers = numbers

            self.number += 0.1
            if self.number == 0.5:
                self.number = 0.1
                return output + 0.1

        return output

    def reset_game(self):
        self.prev_nums = []
        self.nums = []
        return self.get_state()


class environment(gym.Env):

    def __init__(self):
        self.prev_actions = None
        self.interface = OsuInterface()
        self.state = self.interface.get_state()  # Assuming it returns 80x60 screenshot
        self.x = 3.0
        self.y = 3.0
        self.action_space = spaces.MultiDiscrete([96.0, 54.0], dtype=np.float64)

        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(1, 54, 96), dtype=np.uint8)

    def step(self, action):
        next_state, reward, done, info = self.interface.perform_action(action)
        self.state = next_state
        return next_state, reward, done, info

    def reset(self):
        self.state = self.interface.reset_game()
        self.prev_actions = deque(maxlen=2000)
        return self.state


env = environment()


def run_periodically():
    threading.Timer(235, run_periodically).start()
    restart()


run_periodically()

model = A2C("MlpPolicy", env=env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log="logs", learning_rate=0.0003, device="cuda")
# model = PPO.load("ppomodel", env=env)

for i in range(200):
    # model = PPO.load("ppomodel", env=env)

    model.learn(10000, tb_log_name="a2c1_optimized")
    model.save("a2cmodel1")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2cUn.png)

I used a lot of different variants to configure the reward system, `action_space`, etc., but my agent just moves cursors randomly and sometimes hits notes in osu!.

Reward system:

If agent receives 300 points in osu, he receives 10 points reward:

```
100 points - 3 points reward
50 points - 1 point
miss - -3 points
idle - 0 point
```

Comment: I also tried ppo agent, and using continuous action_space, like box, but with this config agent just moves cursor close to the screen corner, and returns coordinates between 1 and 3